# which js file is main script file for loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, package.json

I looked inside loopback's package.json but there was no `main` section in it to indicate its entry point.

Does anyone know which script is the entry point for loopback module?

Comment: I have a "main": "server/server.js" in a loopback package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no `main` section in the `package.json`, it reverts to `index.js` by default.

Answer (score 2):

[index.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/index.js#L5) on loopback's base folder